COnfigure pipewire to run on server without GUI, no sound card
I have an almalinux 9 installation, and I would like to play audio to a DLNA renderer on my network.  The system runs in text mode (no GUI) - and must stay that way.
aplay -l confirms no audio devices available, yet pipewire is already running.  Is there a control panel I can launch (I have an X server running locally) to manage pipewire? If not, how do I configure pipewire to send audio to a DLNA renderer, and create a local audio device I can send audio to.
I read that pavucontrol will manage pipewire too, but pavucontrol cannot create a DLNA sink linked to my DLNA renderer.
